# Rails records not in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I'm looking for the correct way to find books not owned by a user...here are the associations:

Book -

```
has_many :owns, :dependent => :destroy
```

User -

```
has_many :owns, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :owned_books, :through => :owns, source: :book, :dependent => :destroy
```

Own -

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :book
```

I have book views for different titles (for example, `Book.where(title => "Foo")`, or `Book.where(title => "Bar")`, and would like to add a filter where a user can see only books with that title that they do not own. It's pretty obvious to me that this should be a new association within the book model, but I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're talking about excluding those owned by the user:

```
Book.where.not(id: user.owned_book_ids)
```

You can chain additional conditions on there by just appending them.

Comment: That's the perks of having a properly normalized data structure. Queries like that are sometimes surprisingly simple.

Comment: What the magic is this !!!!! Thank you very much, sir :D
`owned_book_ids` @@ I don't see this helper in any other Rails tutorial anywhere ?

Comment: It's a core feature of any `has_many` relationship and is explained in [section 4.3.1 of the Rails guide on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). It's not something you'd recognize unless you really dig into the documentation, so I'm sure a lot of people don't even know it exists.